# Regarding Tags And Categories

Tags: categories, themes, conditional-tags

I wanted to use a new theme for my website, but the problem is, in my current theme, it has spesific tag like for example "abc tag" and in my new one, it doesn't. So if I change my theme, all the posts are gone (404 error).

My question is, is it possible to create a new spesific tag with different name (in this case: abc tag)? or is it possible to migrate the old abc tag to my new one eventhough my new theme doesn't has that tag?

I have tried using elementor but still no luck, any help would be very.. very.. very.. appreciated!

Thank you all!!!  ^_^

Comment: Create a same custom post type, category and tags with same slug in new theme,it will remains as it is in previous theme @Richard

Comment: Hello Gopalak, thank you for your input!

However, I don't think that's possible though. :(

Comment: Have it works by the process of my comment

Comment: If you have free time, could you please check this picture? 
I was talking about the 'videos and blog' section. It's not available in the new theme, so, if I change my theme, all the posts are gone :( 

At least, is it possible to create another 'video' section copy? 
Once again, thanks!

img: https://imgur.com/a/XHg5byR

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you posted on your questions comments, I would assume the Videos, Blog, and Photos are custom post types registered by your current theme. The theme might also register some custom taxonomies for the post types. The post types and taxonomies could also be registered by some theme related plugin.

You should either take a look at the theme's code or see the browsers address field when viewing the Videos, Blog or Photos admin pages to see what names have been used to register the custom post types. The same goes with the any custom taxonomies. You could for example see something like &post_type=videos.

Then just create a custom plugin in which you register the custom post types and taxonomies with the same names to use them after theme change.

Create plugin,
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/

Register post types,
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/

Register taxonomies,
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/

This is what Gopalakrishnan18 was also saying in the comments.